# Рекурсивная функция

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Дано натуральное число n. Выведите все числа от 1 до n. Вот , что выходит. Где ошибка?

[image: рекурсия]

```
int func(int );


int main()


{

    int n;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ) " << func(n) << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



int func(int n)
{

    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return func(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: сперва, подумайте нужен ли вам цикл, вам же по заданию нужно сделать рекурсивно

Comment: Кстати, ваша `func` и не может вернуть ничего, кроме `1`

Comment: @choko: О какой "ошибке" вы вообще ведете речь? Ваша программа успешно выводит все числа от `1` до `n`, как и требовалось. А зачем вы еще приплели сюда какию-то функцию `func`, всегда возвращающую `1`, и зачем вы это `1` печатаете - не ясно. Выкиньте нафиг эту `func`, забудьте про нее, и дело с концом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная функция

```
int func(int n)
{

    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return func(n - 1);
}
```

всегда для значений больше 0 возвращает 1, так как это как раз условие выхода из рекурсии. А для значений меньше 0 имеет неопределенное поведение.:)

Кроме того, если в задании говорится о натуральном ряде чисел, то следует объявлять соответствующую переменную или параметр функции, как имеющий без-знаковый целый тип.

А также в вашем задании имеется в виду, что циклы не будут использоваться. Все должна сделать функция, рекурсивно выводя значения от 1 до `n`.

Все, что от вас требуется, это следующее

```
#include <iostream>

void func(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        func(n - 1);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;

    std::cout << "n = ";

    if (std::cin >> n && n != 0) func(n);
}
```

Вывод программы может выглядеть к примеру так

```
n = 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Все проще:

```
void out(int n)
{
    if (n > 1) out(n-1);
    cout << n << endl;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    out((cout<<"n = ", cin >> n, n));
}
```